# How to have constraints in graph database such as orientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I am coming from the RDBMS world. so forgive if I ask a badly phrased question.

I have a situation where I need to ensure unique or partial unique populating data inside cayley

In RDBMS such as postgres, I can build a table like this:

- primary autoincrement key called id
- foreignkey to person table called person_id
- foreignkey to product table called product_id
- foreignkey to price table called price_id
- boolean field called is_removed

If i want a unique constraint such as the entire table can have a unique index such that product_id and price_id are together as a pair must be unique, I can do that.

if i want a partial unique constraint in postgres where if the is_removed is False, then the person_id, product_id, and price_id are unique.

Then if any of the foreignkeys are null, the constraints are not triggered.

How do I have something this inside a graph database such as orientDB?

My objective is to prevent creating illegal relations in the database

Answer (score 1):

In orientDB you can define a schema for your database.
You have classes instead of tables.
Vertexes and edges are specialized classes.
You can define properties on classes, and define constraints on properties.

As a concrete example, the definition for the a User vertex class :

```
CREATE CLASS User EXTENDS V;
CREATE PROPERTY User.userId LONG;
CREATE PROPERTY User.description STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY User.screenName STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY User.lang STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY User.location STRING;
CREATE PROPERTY User.fetched BOOLEAN;

CREATE INDEX User.userId ON User(userId) UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX METADATA {ignoreNullValues: true};
CREATE INDEX User.description ON User(description) FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE METADATA {ignoreNullValues: true};
```

These are the links to the official part of the documentation about SQL and schema manipulation:

http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Create-Class.html

http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Create-Vertex.html

http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Create-Edge.html

http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Create-Index.html

http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Create-Property.html